# Retrieving getJSON property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON located at ../JSON/addresses.json:

```
[
{
"id":"Cheonan2",
"Field1": "96, 3Gongdan1-ro",
"Field2": "Seobuk-gu, Cheonan-si",
"Field3": "Chungcheongnam-do, 31093, Korea",
"Field4": "",
"Field1K": "31093 충청남도 천안시",
"Field2K": "서북구 3공단1로 96",
"Field3K": "",
"Field4K": ""
}
]
```

How do I retrieve 'id' property when using **$.getJSON**? I tried the following code but console returns 'undefined' error:

```
var JSONAddress = $.getJSON("../JSON/addresses.json",function(){ 
console.log(JSONAddress[0].id);})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we assume you JSON URL return array of `JSONAddress` then you should write:

```
   $.getJSON("../JSON/addresses.json",function(JSONAddress){ 
          console.log(JSONAddress[0].id);
  });
```